# How to fire a uilocalnotification after three days?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am currently working on an iPhone project.
I wanted to fire a local notification after three days of time since the time now.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You switched your accepted answer to one that uses the exact method I said should NOT be used?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update from the other answer here.

60*60*24 is NOT one day and should never be used to mean one day.

If you want a date in three days time then you can use NSCalendar...

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.day = 3;

NSDate *threeDaysTime = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];
```

This is how to calculate three days time. Using 60*60*24 is not correct.

Comment: Yeah!ofcourse When We are dealing in manual caliculations,i think we need to take care of day light saving.Am i correct?

Comment: Exactly :-) daylight savings is one case but there are other times as well when time changes (leap seconds, yes they exist) and so on. Better to catch everything with your code rather than catching 99% with the same amount of code and lose that 1%.

Comment: :) yes!i got you,im new biee to ios and learning from scratch ofcourse!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule it whatever time, from current time like this,

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(60*60*24*3)]; //60 seconds* 60 minutes * 24 hours * 3 days
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Set your message",locations];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

**Update 1**

For Permission about User notification, you have to set in App Delegate like,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Welcome bro, any time. :)

Comment: nope!it's worked for fine...but for ios8 we need to ask permissions right?

Comment: No, I have implemented it iOS8.1 as well, there is no need of permission. Are you facing issue with iOS8??

Comment: logging as not recieved permissins to play sounds,badge,alert and something like this

Comment: I have already done in my case, coz I am using push notification as well, so didn't got that error.

Comment: done with that functionality already bro!its working fine now..no any problems..anyway thanks.

Comment: 60*60*24 is NOT a day! People need to stop using this. You should be using NSCalendar instead.